# Is there an advantage to using *args over **kwargs in python?

Tags: python

So I understand the difference between *args and **kwargs and I use **kwargs regularly in my functions to pass optional arguments. However I never seem to use args because I don't want two of the same argument type to be passed to the function, or I don't want to have to rely on positional inputs to the function, or a variety of other more context specific reasons for using **kwargs over *args.

Is there a scenario, or a type of use case where using *args would be preferable to using **kwargs?

Comment: `**kwargs` is useful for passing optional arguments. `*args` is useful for passing an undetermined number of arguments that _don't need to be individually named_.

Comment: Personally I believe that variadic functions are an unnecessary language complication for the minimally-valuable purpose of avoiding typing the couple extra characters it takes to explicitly construct a list. In practice I think whether you use them in Python really just comes down to aesthetic preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` would be preferable for any function that performs an operation over an array with no limit, for example:

```
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for num in args:
        total = total + num
    return total
```

I can call `add` with any amount of parameters:

```
add(1, 2, 2) #  5
add(1) #  1
add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) #  28
```

Comment: Once again though, I would never do something like this, I would pass the array of numbers to the function, which would require one argument, and I would use that as a formal argument.

Is my preference for passing the array of numbers just the work of a neophyte? I still can't see a reason for using this.

Comment: Sometimes when you know most use case will involved a fixed number of arguments that are not contained in a list, yet you don't know that number because you don't know the use case, it's cleaner to use `*args`.  Consider `zip`.  It much nicer to write `zip(list1, list2)` or `zip(l1,l2,l3)` than `zip([list1, list2])` or `zip([l1, l2, l3])`.

Comment: For such a simple example it makes sense to pass an array of numbers as well. I would say that `*args` reads better and is more pythonic.

Comment: @Jim Wright, yeah, I'm glad you agree, however Lærne, I do see your point there. Passing a list in that case doesn't make sense, it seems like one more unnecessary step. Concatenation functions was the only example that I could think of though. Can you think of any other example?

Comment: I can't think of any other generic examples, no. But it is down to your opinion also.

Comment: @DanWhite `*args` is mostly used to support call delegation, such as function decorators.

Comment: Just a few days after having to ask why on earth would I ever do this, I'm writing a function where using *args is the only reasonable solution. The function requests information about a series of data fields, the number of data fields is variable, from one to whatever and passing a list of field names is cumbersome.

Comment: @Matias Cicero, I haven't gotten into function decorators yet. I tried reading about them but I didn't have enough background knowledge to make sense of them. I'll also read about call delegation, which I have never heard of. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Thanks to `*args`, you can:

```
itertools.chain([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False, False])
```

If we would opt to use `**kwargs` instead of `*args`, we would need to define some kind of naming standard so the user can pass in as many iterables as he/she wants.

The calling code would end up being something like this:

```
itertools.chain(seq1=[1,2,3], seq2=['a','b','c'], seq3=[True, False, False])
```

Which isn't really nice at all.

So, `*args` is really useful when dealing with an unknown length of arguments.